# Prove or disprove the given equivalence

Tags: asymptotics, landau-notation

f(n) = n/100 = Ω(n) . I am new at proving asymptotic notations , especially at big-Ω. That's why I even didnt start the beginning myself.  I tried to prove myself as looking at other proofs and searched on the internet to find same question but I couldnt find. I dont think so this question is a duplicate of another which was asked here. Thanks for helps.

Comment: Could you please post what you tried to solve it yourself? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume $n$ takes only positive values. By the definition of [Big-Omega](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations) you could prove it by showing the following

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\frac{n}{100}}{n} >0$$

The rest is a simple exercise.